# ZF2 Properties name in model does not correspond to database columns

Tags: php, forms, doctrine-orm, zend-framework2, hydration

I have a `User` `model` that contains some properties-let's say `firstName` `and` `lastName`-but in my database I store them as `first_name` `and` `last_name`.

inside `User` `Form` I use a hydrator like so:

```
$this->setHydrator(new ClassMethods(true));
```

The debug shows:

```
array(5) {
  ["firstName"] => string(13) "my first name"
  ["lastName"] => string(12) "my last name"
  ...
}
```

Why do the array keys not match the database columns, even I use `$this->setHydrator(new ClassMethods(true));` ?

Comment: You don't mention how your getters and setters are defined, but I'll venture a guess that you have getFirstName and setFirstName. This is what the ClassMethods hydrator uses.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem for mapping my database columns to `User` Model by setting naming strategy on the hydrator, here is my code:

```
$hydrator = new ClassMethods(false);
$namingStrategy = new \Zend\Hydrator\NamingStrategy\UnderscoreNamingStrategy();       
$hydrator->setNamingStrategy($namingStrategy);
```

Answer (score 0):

In Doctrine you work with an object model separate from your database model meaning that column names and property names are not necessarily the same. In your entity definitions you can explicitly declare your column names and then Doctrine will make sure that the property names are mapped to the correct column names in the **[UnitOfWork](http://doctrine2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/working-with-objects.html#synchronization-with-the-database)** when persisting changes to the database.

You declare column names in the `@Column` annotations in your entity definitions as follows:

```
/** @Column(type="string", name="first_name") */
private $firstName;

/** @Column(type="string", name="last_name") */
private $lastName;
```

You can read more on this [in the doctrine documentation chapter **4.3. Property mapping**](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.io/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/basic-mapping.html#property-mapping).

Like this you can have an object model that is independent from your database model. So in your debug you see your object model properties, not your database column names. I hope this explanation helps you to understand the differences.